Using capacitor filesystem downloadFile cause other func to be blocked?
Hello guys I notice this issue and I'm struggling to find solution.
when I use the capacitor `

FileSystem.downloadFile()

`
the other plugin of capacitor being called is being blocked and was execute after the download File has finish.
regarding if I'm using async await I try to remove it but it's the same all capacitor plugin called is stop and continue until the download has finished any suggestion>
